# Trailing Space to Superview Ignored in ScrollView Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm currently working in Storyboard view in Xcode 6. I have a ScrollView container with several button elements. I would like to have a row of 3 elements with the first and last aligning to their respective (left or right) edges.

The problem I'm having is with the 3rd element. I've been setting its trailing space to 10 to the Superview, but the element does not appear on screen.  The ScrollView has constraints set to 0 for all edges.

I've done similar without a ScrollView and the spacing is set properly, it's only within the ScrollView that it is not aligning properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ScrollView treats constraints differently. It uses leading/trailing constraints to determine how far the content can be scrolled. So when you create a trailing constraint with constant == 10, scroll view thinks, that if your views don't fit into ScrollView horizontally, and user tries to scroll them, there should be 10 points wide empty space on the right from the third view.

If I understand you correctly, you want your three views to fit on the screen (horizontally). In this case, in addition to leading/trailing constraints, you have to set their width somehow.

The most practical way to do it (from my point of view) is to add some sort of contentView to your scrollView, so that other views become subviews of that contentView. Then you add leading/trailing constraints from the contentView to the scrollView **and a width constraint for the contentView** (for instance, leading/trailing constraints with const == 0 and contentView.width == scrollView.width). Then you can add your views as subviews of the contentView as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Put a view inside the scrollView.
Set constraints on the view
leading, trailing, top, bottom, height, width.

Add your buttons inside that view, set the constraints as required. They will be shown correctly.

To manage the scrollView contentSize just update the constraints of the container view (which you have added inside scrollView)
Like if you don't want horizontal scrolling then update like

```
self.myViewWidthConstraint.constant =320;
[self.myView updateConstraints];
```